# How to calculate constraint force for angle constraint in CP2K NVT MD simulation?

Tags: cp2k, aimd

I am running a CP2K NVT molecular dynamics simulation and want to apply an angle constraint between three atoms. In my previous simulations, I used a bond constraint between two atoms, and it was easy to obtain the constraint force by multiplying the output Lagrange multiplier with the constrained bond length. However, I am not sure how to calculate the constraint force when I have an angle constraint instead of a bond constraint.

Can anyone suggest a way to obtain the constraint force for an angle constraint in CP2K NVT MD simulation? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been more than 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!

Comment: @NikeDattani I think CP2K prints the free energy if I used Umbrella Sampling instead. But it seems that with constraint dynamics, the process of calculating free energy for non-trivial collective variables is more involved (https://pubs.aip.org/jcp/article/109/18/7737/183350/Free-energy-from-constrained-molecular-dynamics).

Comment: Are you able to write a self-answer? If not, I wonder whether or not you're still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question?